# Not Hamiltonian is in NP Class?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, np-hard, decision-problem

I ask a question before, [Questions on Graph and Hamiltonian](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/39496/questions-on-graph-and-hamiltonian), but i ask it here with different challenging contest.

From [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=8535vmYbLGYC&pg=PA400&lpg=PA400&dq=whether%20a%20graph%20is%20%20%22not%20Hamiltonian%22%20is%20an%20NP-complete%20problem&source=bl&ots=pi_z-iZrnP&sig=RYHYyl0woD6pQgGYSa7M_STxbpw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RHbjVLyRFoH1Uu_5gZgN&ved=0CMgBEOgBMBs#v=onepage&q=whether%20a%20graph%20is%20%20%22not%20Hamiltonian%22%20is%20an%20NP-complete%20problem&f=false) and other study in complexity theory, I have seen the following statement:

> The definition of NP is not symmetric with respect to yes-instances and no-instances.  For example, it is an open question whether the following problem belongs to NP: given a graph G, is it true that G is not Hamiltonian?

However, I was wondering if this this problem was NP-Complete.  Could someone let me know if the following statement true?

> Determining a that a Graph is not Hamiltonian is in NP-Class.

I read another book on [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=eZi8AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA306&dq=not+a+given+graph+is+hamiltonian+is+NP-hard&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sankVLbYF4TzUtnNgsgC&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=not%20a%20given%20graph%20is%20hamiltonian%20is%20NP-hard&f=false) on end of page 306, the authors wrote this is NP-Hard. anyone could clarify me?

Comment: Don't you already have an answer? Your first quote states that deciding if a graph is not Hamiltonian is not known to be in NP. So we don't know; it's an open problem whether it is in NP or not.

Comment: @Juho, my main problem is, given graph is not Hamiltonian is in NP class is T or F?

Comment: so, @Juho, Why the authors wrote is NP-Hard?

Comment: They did not claim that. They wrote that deciding if a graph is Hamiltonian or not is NP-hard. Maybe your main issue is with English and the way the problem(s) are stated.

Comment: @Juho, Would you please describe a little for me as an answeR?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, please read the first sentence !!

Comment: I also agree this is a duplicate. You already have a complete answer in the previous question. If it feels confusing, it might help to really stop, take a deep breath, and work carefully through the statements.

Comment: would you learn me @Juho?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement

> Determining a that a Graph is not Hamiltonian is in NP-Class.

is neither true nor false. It doesn't have a truth value, since there's a type mismatch. Similarly, the statement

> The color red is in NP.

is neither true nor false.

Here is something which is true. Let $L$ be the language of all Hamiltonian graphs. That is, $x \in L$ if $x$ encodes a Hamiltonian graph. (We fix the encoding once and for all.) The language $L$ is in NP since to prove that $x \in L$, one just needs to present a Hamiltonian circuit (a proof whose size is polynomial in the input size), and this proof can be verified in polynomial time.

Furthermore, $L$ is NP-complete. The book you're consulting probably has a proof. Therefore, if $L$ were in coNP, then NP=coNP, which is believed to be false. So it is probably the case that $L$ is not in coNP. But we don't know for sure.

The language $L'$ of non-Hamiltonian graphs is the complement of $L$ (modulo boring technicalities arising from the fact that not every string encodes a graph). Since $L$ is NP, $L'$ is in coNP. We can also see it directly: to prove that $x \notin L'$, one just needs to present a Hamiltonian circuit.

Furthermore, $L'$ is coNP-complete, since $L$ is NP-complete. Again, it is probably the case that $L'$ is not in coNP, since otherwise NP=coNP, which is believed to be false.